# Select specific sheet based on cell value with loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new with programming and I am trying to finish a small Project for my Company. I am trying to write a code that loops through a range and for every cell.value greater than 0 it will find corresponding excel sheet and execute the specific code. Thank you!

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("B3:B53")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell > 0 Then
        SheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Select
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
        Range("E4:P50").Select
        Selection.ClearContest
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: I think you could try `If cell.Value>0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
If cell > 0 Then
    dim ws as worksheet
    set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value)
    ws.PrintOut Copies:=1
    ws.Range("E4:P50").ClearContest
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("B3:B53")

On Error Resume Next
For Each Cell In rng
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
        Set ws = Sheets(Cell.Value)
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            With ws
                .PrintOut Copies:=1
                .Range("E4:P50").ClearContents
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I run the code i get following error: "Index out of bounds". Do you know what to do?

Comment: Sorry your code worked, partly. But when i try to execute the code, instead of only printing out the sheets which were found in Range("B3:B53"), which has a cell value greater than zero, it printed out every sheet (including empty cells inside the range).

Comment: Doesnt work... But I Think I know what's wrong! The Range("B3:B53") is in an external sheet and not in the same sheet as corresponding cell.value. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Change `Sheets(1)` to the sheet you neee.

Comment: When i change Sheets(1) to Sheets("div") and execute the macro, nothing happends... (div is the name of the sheet with the macrobutton and where the range is)

Comment: Uncomment the `On Error` - Statement and go throught the code with `F8`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for..
A simple code

```
Dim cell            As Range
Dim cell2           As Range
Dim cell3           As Range

    Set cell = Cells.Find(What:="Your Value", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set cell2 = Cells.Find(What:="Your Value", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set cell3 = Cells.Find(What:="Your Value", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    'Your code
Else
    'Your code
End If

If cell2 Is Nothing Then
    'Your code
Else
    'Your code
End If

If cell3 Is Nothing Then
    'Your code
Else
    'Your code
End If
```

You can add more cell values by setting its variables.

Please let us know if you have any query..

Comment: Thank you for your code! Unfortunately the amount of sheets my book has is >50 so doing your way would be very tedious.... UGPs answer is what I was looking for but i can't get it to work.