# How do I set a column to search in using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to carry out a search in Column B only but with the code below the whole worksheet is being searched. How do I change my code to search only column B?

```
Columns("B:B").Select

                Cells.Find(What:=Region, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: Drop `Select` and try `Columns("B:B").Find(...)`

Comment: Check below if this helps[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562344/select-specific-sheet-based-on-cell-value-with-loop/45566360?noredirect=1#comment78091906_45566360)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Columns("B:B").Find(What:=Region, After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: when I use  Columns("B:B").Find(What....) I receive runtime error 13 type mismatch what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I changed `After` parameter from `ActiveCell` to `Range("B1")`. Check if that helps.